# Implement Lazy Proxy in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

The Simple Injector docs [describe](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#lazy) how to implement a lazy dependency. However, this example only covers registering a simple interface (`IMyService`). How would this work with an open generic (EG. `IMyService<T>`)?

Here's my existing registration:

```
container.Register(typeof(IDbRepository<>), typeof(DbRepository<>));
```

Obviously the following code doesn't compile as I'm not specifying the generic type:

```
container.Register(typeof(IDbRepository<>),
    () => new LazyDbRepositoryProxy<>(new Lazy<IDbRepository<>(container.GetInstance<>)));
```

Is this possible in Simple Injector? I can only see the following overrides for Register, non of which allow a func / instanceCreator to be passed in:

```
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, params Assembly[] assemblies);
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies);
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, Assembly assembly, Lifestyle lifestyle);
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies, Lifestyle);
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, IEnumerable<Type> implementationTypes, Lifestyle);
public void Register(Type openGenericServiceType, IEnumerable<Type> implementationTypes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code construct such as you suggested is not one you can express in C#. But by making a small change to your design, you can elegantly solve your problem.

The trick is to inject `Container` into your `LazyDbRepositoryProxy<T>`. This way, Simple Injector can easily construct new `LazyDbRepositoryProxy<T>` instances using auto-wiring which prevents you from having to register a delegate (which won't work for open-generic types).

So change your `LazyDbRepositoryProxy<T>` to the following:

```cs
// As this type depends on your DI library, you should place this type inside your
// Composition Root.
public class LazyDbRepositoryProxy<T> : IDbRepository<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<DbRepository<T>> wrapped;

    public LazyDbRepositoryProxy(Container container)
    {
        this.wrapped = new Lazy<IMyService>(container.GetInstance<DbRepository<T>>));
    }
}
```

And register your types as follows:

```cs
container.Register(typeof(DbRepository<>));
container.Register(typeof(IDbRepository<>), typeof(LazyDbRepositoryProxy<>));
```

Comment: Hi @steven. I've tried the above with a small correction to the code:

`public LazyDbRepositoryProxy(Container container)
{
    wrapped = new Lazy<IDbRepository<T>>(() => container.GetInstance<DbRepository<T>>());
}`

And it's all working - thanks!